# How to Display created records in ASP.NET Web Application to my Xamarin.Forms.Droid

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Good Day. I'm trying to display all the data created in ASP.NET Web Application to my Xamarin.Forms.Droid. I tried to CRUD records thru UWP and was able to display the data in a Local Machine.

[image]

But what I want is to display the list of created records to my XamarinForms.Droid? I don't know why it doesn't appear in my mobile.

Here's my XAML codes.

MainPageMain.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.MainPageMain"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo">


  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList, Mode=TwoWay}"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
          <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

           <Image Source="icon.png"
               HeightRequest="66"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               WidthRequest="66"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               />


        <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                   Padding="12,6">-->
        <Label Grid.Column="1"
          Text="{Binding Name}"
               FontSize="24"/>

        <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{Binding Department}"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>

            <!--</StackLayout>-->
          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

  </ListView>

  <Label Text="Read This PLS!"/>

  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here's my code in retrieving Web API.

RestClient.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Plugin.RestClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// RestClient implements methods for calling CRUD operations
    /// using HTTP.
    /// </summary>
    public class RestClient<T>
    {

        private const string WebServiceUrl = "http://localhost:50857/api/Employees/";

        public async Task<List<T>> GetAsync()
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(WebServiceUrl);

           var taskModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

            return taskModels;
        }

    public async Task<bool> PostAsync(T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(WebServiceUrl, httpContent);

        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

    public async Task<bool> PutAsync(int id, T t)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var result = await httpClient.PutAsync(WebServiceUrl + id, httpContent);

        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }

        public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int id, T t)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(WebServiceUrl + id);

            return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }
}
```

.

Here's my code for the MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Models;
using XamarinFormsDemo.Services;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private List<Employee> _employeesList;
    private Employee _selectedEmployee = new Employee();




    public List<Employee> EmployeesList
    {
        get { return _employeesList; }
        set
        {
            _employeesList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }



    public MainViewModel()
    {
        InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {
        var employeesServices = new EmployeesServices();

        EmployeesList = await employeesServices.GetEmployeesAsync();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you are retrieving data from the Web Api?

Comment: And XAML, how do you display all

Comment: @DanielKrzyczkowski I've added my codes Sir.

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy  I've added my codes Sir.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista and `MainViewModel`. Thanks

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy oh sorry Sir. I've added it again. Thanks :)

Comment: First thing: could you try to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Yes Sir. I've tried that before. Unfortunately, it didn't worked :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115480/discussion-between-egor-gromadskiy-and-jaycee-evangelista).